# Analog of CRM 4 methods CrmService.CreateAsync(UpdateAsync) in CRM 2011

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Is it possible to make asyncs calls, like it was in Crm 4

```
  crmService.UpdateAsync(card, Guid.NewGuid());
```

in CRM 2011???

I have to do synchronization between CRM and some system with the help of SSIS. 
In destination script component I'd like to use Async calls, but I don't want to write async calls on my own.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest.aspx) could be answer for this question, but it's possible only in CRM 2011 UR 12

```
 #region Execute Multiple with Results
// Create an ExecuteMultipleRequest object.
requestWithResults = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
{
    // Assign settings that define execution behavior: continue on error, return responses. 
    Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
    {
        ContinueOnError = false,
        ReturnResponses = true
    },
    // Create an empty organization request collection.
    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
};

// Create several (local, in memory) entities in a collection. 
EntityCollection input = GetCollectionOfEntitiesToCreate();

// Add a CreateRequest for each entity to the request collection.
foreach (var entity in input.Entities)
{
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest { Target = entity };
    requestWithResults.Requests.Add(createRequest);
}

// Execute all the requests in the request collection using a single web method call.
ExecuteMultipleResponse responseWithResults =
    (ExecuteMultipleResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(requestWithResults);

// Display the results returned in the responses.
foreach (var responseItem in responseWithResults.Responses)
{
    // A valid response.
    if (responseItem.Response != null)
        DisplayResponse(requestWithResults.Requests[responseItem.RequestIndex], responseItem.Response);

    // An error has occurred.
    else if (responseItem.Fault != null)
        DisplayFault(requestWithResults.Requests[responseItem.RequestIndex], 
            responseItem.RequestIndex, responseItem.Fault);
}
```

Code from MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I've mainly worked with CRM 2011 (as opposed to CRM 4) but it sounds like you're about to deploy a plugin. If not, stop reading now. :)

If you are, you can set the type of call to asynchronous while registering your plugin in the PRT. Just click for the option.

You've also got another option. If you're running the newest .NET framework, there's a new keyword - *async* that executes the method asynchronously. And if you're targeting an older .NET version, don't despair - I used threads for a lengthy update and that worked out quite well too.